# Корреляция графиков

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, визуализация, статический-анализ

Не могу прокоррелировать два графика, помогите.

Есть csv файл:

```
99.0
86.0
87.0
64.0
46.0
75.0
59.0
58.0
```

плюс есть график:

```
np.exp(-t) * np.cos(2 * np.pi * t)------[t = np.arange(0.6, 5.0, 0.1)]
```

Подскажите, как их можно прокорелировать, и по возможности показать это на графике

Comment: Если значания из `csv` файла - это значения какой-то функции, то где соответствующая область определения?

Comment: эти я достал из сайта Google trends, поэтому их области определения я не знаю.

Comment: Вы можете уточнить вопрос? Что и как вы хотите "прокоррелировать"?

Comment: хочу определить коеф. пирсона, для участков . через цикл увеличивать размерность графика функции, и корелировать их с кусками графика по нашему csv. Таким образом мы можем узнать, в каких кусках идёт максимальное подобие с графиком.

Answer (score 1):

Если вопрос в сравнении графиков, то можно скалировать обе функции чтобы диапазон значений лежал в интервале `[0, 1]` и только потом чертить графики:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

def minmax_scale(a):
    return (a - a.min()) / (a.max() - a.min())

t = np.arange(0.6, 5.0, 0.1)
y = np.exp(-t) * np.cos(2 * np.pi * t)


tr = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, squeeze=True)

plt.plot(t, minmax_scale(y))
minmax_scale(tr).plot()
ax = plt.gca()
ax.legend(handles=['Function', 'Google Trend'])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS в качестве значений `x` для `Google Trend` использовались целые числа от нуля - лучше конечно найти какой-нибудь "общий знаменатель" для области определения обоих графиков...

---

**UPDATE:** чтобы посчитать коэффициент корреляции Пирсона двух векторов - оба этих вектора должны иметь одинаковую длину:

```
In [40]: np.corrcoef(tr, y)
...
skipped
...
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly
```

пример:

```
In [41]: len(tr)
Out[41]: 8

In [42]: np.corrcoef(tr, y[:8])
Out[42]:
array([[ 1.        , -0.66867183],
       [-0.66867183,  1.        ]])
```

или для последних 8-ми элементов вектора `y`:

```
In [43]: np.corrcoef(tr, y[-8:])
Out[43]:
array([[1.        , 0.10253215],
       [0.10253215, 1.        ]])
```

Comment: `import numpy as np` забыли)

Comment: @Twiss, да, спасибо, добавил

Comment: Вы знакомы из коэффициентом корреляции Пирсона? В Pythone корреляция реализуется  в numpy.corrcoef и scipy.stats.pearsonr. Так что наверное вы меня неправильно поняли

Comment: @Cheshiree, чтобы воспользоваться коэффициентом корреляции Пирсона вектора на входе должны иметь одинаковую длину (размерность). В вашем примере это не так.

Comment: в случае с графиком мы можем менять размерность по нашему усмотрению, поэтому кажеться это не большая проблема. 
А вообще тут заковырка в другом. надо начать из самых маленьких кусочков(размерностей) графика, и через цикл определять коэф. пирсона, и так далее, увеличивая размер куска графика. а потом уже это представить в графическом виде. что то типа двохуровневой матрицы "тепловая карта"

Comment: @Cheshiree, попробуйте сфопмулировать вопрос так, чтобы было понятно что вы хотите сделать и привести соответствующие примеры входных и выходных данных. [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 0):

Для вычисления коэффициента корреляции надо иметь 3 ряда: значения аргумента (они в условии не приводятся, так что надо их где-то "найти"), значения данных в этих точках, они в файле CSV, видимо. И третий ряд надо вычислить по формуле по значениям аргумента.